# Error executing gcc in Z shell script

Tags: zsh

If I run this script: (Note: edited to reflect answer 1)

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt shwordsplit

if [[ -f $1 ]]
then
   echo "will compile $1"
else
  echo "ERROR: $1 NOT found"
  exit 1
fi

gcc_options="  -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  "

echo "gcc_options: ${gcc_options}"

gcc " ${=gcc_options} " " ${=1} "

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "gcc compile worked"
else
   echo "error in gcc compile"
fi

gcc "${=gcc_options}" "${=1}"

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "gcc compile worked"
else
   echo "error in gcc compile"
fi
```

Both compiles fail.

Output is:

---

will compile my_file.c
gcc_options:   -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
gcc: error:  : No such file or directory
gcc: error:  : No such file or directory
gcc: error: my_file.c : No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files  compilation terminated.
error in gcc compile
gcc: error: : No such file or directory
gcc: error: : No such file or directory
error in gcc compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change:

```
gcc " $gcc_options $1"
```

To:

```
gcc "$gcc_options" "$1"
```

If some of these variables contain multiple words, you may need to turn on `shwordsplit` (see [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/files/prettify-1-Jun-2011.tar.bz2)), which can also be done on a per variable basis (`${=VAR}`).

```
gcc "${=gcc_options}" "${=1}"
```

#### Update

I made a mistake, you definitely don't want quotes on `$gcc_options`, so it should probably be `${=gcc_options}`. If you need to quote `$1` depends if `$1` contains spaces. So this should do:

```
gcc ${=gcc_options} $1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the quotes, but still get the error. I added "setopt shwordsplit" and still get the error. I modified it to be "${=gcc_options} "${=1}". That didn't succeed, but my error is different: gcc: error: : No such file or directory
gcc: error: : No such file or directory

Comment: Somewhere they mention putting separate words into an array: gcc_options_array=(-c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra) and that does work: gcc $gcc_options_array $1.

Comment: Running this: #!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt shwordsplit

if [[ -f $1 ]]
then
   echo "will compile $1"
else
  echo "ERROR: $1 NOT found"
  exit 1
fi

gcc_options="  -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  "

echo "gcc_options: ${gcc_options}"

gcc " ${=gcc_options} " " ${=1} "

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "gcc compile worked"
else
   echo "error in gcc compile"
fi

gcc "${=gcc_options}" "${=1}"

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
   echo "gcc compile worked"
else
   echo "error in gcc compile"
fi

Comment: gives this output: will compile my_file.c
gcc_options:   -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra  
gcc: error:  : No such file or directory
gcc: error:  : No such file or directory
gcc: error:  assertions.c : No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error in gcc compile
gcc: error: : No such file or directory
gcc: error: : No such file or directory
error in gcc compile

Comment: @Scooter: I may have made a mistake and added an update, does that answer your question?